# How to use azure-pipeline.yml to trigger for different enviornment DEV, SIT, UAT in azure-devops

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, environment, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have azure-pipeline.yml, and use the same file to run on DEV, SIT, UAT environments using if elif conditions, to identify the branch name and environment to be deployed on,

Example:
if [[ $BRANCH_NAME == "develop" ]]
then
env="app-dev"
ns="app-dev"
elif [[ $TAG_NAME == RC-UAT-* ]]
then
env="app-uat"
ns="app-uat"

I want to know the best way possible to do the same, where I can templatize my yml file and identify which branch is triggered, and pipeline is running for which environment.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you checked the documentation? What specific difficulties are you having?

Comment: I have tried using if else condition in yaml file. The difficulty is that instead of having conditions like if else, I want to know what could be the best way of handling such scenario, of pipeline to run on Dev, sit uat environments with single YAML file.

Comment: Post your pipeline. Show what you've tried. That said, having a branch per environment is considered a bad practice to begin with. You should have a branch that is the source of deployments, and then a single deployment is promoted from lower environments to higher environments.

Answer (score 0):

You could use "Condition" in your pipeline. For details, please refer to this document: [Conditions - Azure Pipelines | Microsoft Docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/conditions?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml).

According your requirements, I also tried the following YAML example:

```
variables:
  isMain: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/main')]
  isDev: $[eq(variables['Build.SourceBranch'], 'refs/heads/dev')]
stages:
- stage: A
  jobs:
  - job: A1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage A!
- stage: B
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isMain, 'true'))
  jobs:
  - job: B1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage B!
      - script: echo $(isMain)
- stage: C
  condition: and(succeeded(), eq(variables.isDev, 'true'))
  dependsOn: []
  jobs:
  - job: C1
    steps:
      - script: echo Hello Stage C!
      - script: echo $(isMain)
```

When I trigger pipeline with the 'main' branch, the stage C will be skipped.
When I trigger pipeline with the 'dev' branch, the stage B will be skipped.

Therefore, you could adapt the above example to design you "if else" pipeline.

Comment: Hi @Priyanka Sharma, is there any updates for this question? Please feel free to let me know whether the answers above can help you and feel free to comment~ Just a remind of [this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235).

Comment: condition is what I am already using, to trigger the pipeline when different branch names matches. My whole idea behind this question is that I have a bunch of if else conditions in my pipeline, 
`if [[ $BRANCH_NAME == "develop" ]] then env="app-dev" ns="app-dev" elif [[ $TAG_NAME == RC-UAT-* ]] then env="app-uat" ns="app-uat"`
which sets variables, like if branch name is develop then set env as app-dev, else set it to null and so on.. 
Can this be parametrized in such a manner that I can remove that if else.